24.04 Ubuntu crashes periodiocally, screen freezes
I have the same problem as this solved on this post:
24.04 Ubuntu crashes periodiocally, screen, keyboard and mouse freeze
I use Ubuntu 24.04 on a laptop. Sometimes, my screen crashes and I have either to close and re-open it or to force shutdown of the computer.
I don't know how to verify the GPU drivers as it seems that this problem could come from there, could anyone help me?
Thanks!
'''
Rapport d’informations du système

Détails du compte rendu

Date de génération :                         2024-11-24 18:39:12

Informations liées au matériel :

Modèle du matériel :                         FUJITSU LIFEBOOK E548
Mémoire :                                    8.0 Gio
Processeur :                                 Intel® Core™ i5-8350U × 8
Carte graphique :                            Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
Capacité du disque :                         512.1 Go

Informations liées au logiciel :

Version du micrologiciel :                   Version 1.26
Nom du système d’exploitation :              Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Construction du système d’exploitation :     (null)
Type de système d’exploitation :             64 bits
Version de GNOME :                           46
Système de fenêtrage :                       X11
Version du noyau :                           Linux 6.8.0-49-generic
'''


It looks like you are using Intel integrated graphics. By any chance are you using TLP for power management? I had some freezes on a laptop with Intel Core i5 processors which were resolved by adding
NMI_WATCHDOG=1 

to /etc/tlp.conf
Also, there are some tips on the ArchWiki you can look at:
Crash/freeze on low power Intel CPUs

Hi,
Thanks for your answer. I don't think I use TLP. I didn't knew what is was. How can I check if I use it?
It seems there is no tlp.conf in the /etc folder. I suppose that means TLP is not installed.

Correct, if there is no file /etc/tlp.conf then you (almost certainly) don't have TLP installed. The ArchWiki article is still worth checking out, since it has several other suggestions.

Hi, do you have suggestions of something I could do? I don't even understand how to update or change my GPU drivers, if the problem comes from there.Thanks!

I doubt if it is a GPU driver issue since you are using the Intel integrated graphics. Sorry, I don't have any suggestions beyond what is in the ArchWiki article.
